# How do I change address books in gnome-contacts?

Tags: online-accounts

How do I reset the settings of gnome-contacts?  I want to switch from the local address book to use the GMail address book.

When gnome-contacts is launched for the first time it offers us two choices, but once the choice is made, is  not possible to reconfigure it. I looked in `/home` for the settings, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 5):

You can rerun the "first time setup" of gnome contacts by opening dconf-editor (maybe you need to install it) and changing org/gnome/Contacts/did-inital-setup to false.

Comment: imho...this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Contacts` menu, pick `Change Address Book...`.  You should be given the same choices as the first time you launched the application.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry the address book option, _Change Address Book..._ does not propose the online address book, only local. But I found how to do;  **You can access it by running a terminal or pressing ALT+F2 and then entering:**  `code` gnome-control-center online-accounts

Comment: Oh?  For me it lists `Local Address Book` and `Contacts`.  The second one shows my Google contacts.

Comment: Maybe when the online option has been clicked on first launch?

Answer (score 1):

3n1c47's solution (gnome-control-center online-accounts) on how to add Online Accounts to Gnome, which adds the online address  book back in to gnome-contacts, was the solution for me as well.

3n1C47 was correct in that, once you've selected Local Address Book, you are never subsequently given an option to add an online address book.  You must do this through Online Accounts.