# How do you sync online accounts with the new contacts program in 12.10?

Tags: sync, 12.10, contacts

I am trying to sync my online accounts (google, facebook, anything really) with the new program in Ubuntu 12.10. It gives me the option to change the address book but I can't see how to set up an online account anywhere.

Anyone have any ideas? Am I just not looking in the right place?

Comment: Update: I tried the fix described in the answer to [this question][1].

This did not work for me. I am still unable to sync my contacts. I did not set up online contacts the first time I opened the new contacts program. Now I do not have the option to add/sync any online contacts. I still need help fixing this. Anyone have any suggestions?

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/q/156490/94780

Comment: (note that this is comprehensively broken in 13.04 for reasons too inane to explain here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to FIRST set up contacts in Evolution.

Then they should show up in your local address book in the contacts program.

For more help, refer to the following question:
[How do I change address books in gnome-contacts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/156490/94780)

If this answer helped you out, please up-vote it.